# Connect to a cluster with password through ES

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I connect to a cluster that have a password through Elasticsearch? I use Sense to work with ES. Right now XGET  through ES returns me:
Authorisation required

Comment: Have you tried to include the username/password in your server address, i.e. `username:password@localhost:9200` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the username/password in your server address directly in Sense, i.e. instead of

```
localhost:9200
```

use this:

```
username:password@localhost:9200
```